# Anti Derivatives of Product Rule

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the anti-derivatives of the following, given that F(x) and G(x) are the anti-derivatives of f(x) and g(x), respectively.

1. $f(x) + g(x) \rightarrow$ would this just be $F(x) + G(x) +c$?
2. $f(x)G(x) + F(x)g(x) \rightarrow$? I recognize this as the product rule, but how do I find the antiderivative of this? I know the antiderviative of $f(x)$ is $F(x)$, but what is the anti-derivative of $F(x)$?

Sorry if this is very easy, it's late in the semester and my brain is fried. Thank you for the help!

Comment: For 2, what is the derivative of $FG$?

Answer (score 1):

Since differentiation is linear, we know that $(F+G)'=F'+G'=f+g$. Hence, $F+G$ is an antiderivative of $f+g$ (this is what we *mean* by antiderivative). We often write this as
$$
\int f(x)+g(x) \, dx = F(x)+G(x) + C \, ,
$$
to emphasise that any function of the form $\phi(x)=F(x)+G(x)+C$ for some number $C$ satisfies $\phi'(x)=f(x)+g(x)$. We also have that $$(F\cdot G)'=\left(F'\cdot G\right)+\left(F \cdot G'\right)=\left(f \cdot G\right)+\left(F\cdot g\right) \, ,$$
and we can adopt the same notation as before.

Answer (score 0):

A couple notes:
$$\int[f(x)+g(x)]\,dx=\int f(x)\,dx+\int g(x)\,dx$$

---

$$\frac{d}{dx}[F(x)G(x)]=F(x)G'(x)+F'(x)G(x)=F(x)g(x)+f(x)G(x)$$